# How does Castle Crashers keep player's progress?

Tags: castle-crashers

To make it more clear I'll use an example. Let's say I play a bit with Green Knight. I get him up to a certain level, unlock some weapons, etc. Then I play some more with a friend on local multiplayer using other characters like Red and Blue Knight.

1. Are the weapons, story progress, experience, etc shared between these play sessions?
2. Can I lose anything by switching to other characters?
3. Is it that no matter how/what/when I play I can keep my unlocks and have them available to other characters during other play sessions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, all progress made in single player is transferred to multi player.

Weapons, gold, story progress, and experience are all different for each character.

You don't lose weapons or animals when switching characters everything else depends on which character you play with.

The story progression in multiplayer also depends on who is hosting the game. So for instance your friend beat the game but you haven't, you will still be able to play the final level.

Also as a word of advice: When you are playing a higher level area with a person with a lower level character, make sure the lowest level person gets the weapon last because if they pick it up and are too low level too equip it, it disappears instead of them throwing their old weapon. (They still get it)